# Einstein Summation Problem

Tags: general-relativity, tensor-calculus

I am a bit confused about Einstein summation. What should the following expression expand into? (To simplify things, let we have only 2 dimensions)

${a_{00}^i}{b_{i1}^1}$

1. ${a_{00}^0}{b_{01}^1}+ {a_{00}^1}{b_{11}^1}$
   [here we assume the same i for both of the terms].
2. ${a_{00}^0}{b_{01}^1}+ 
   {a_{00}^0}{b_{11}^1}+
   {a_{00}^1}{b_{01}^1}+
   {a_{00}^1}{b_{11}^1}$
   [All possible combinations].

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation

Comment: Think about $\vec a\cdot\vec b=a_ib_i$ for 3D Cartesian vectors.

Comment: The important thing to understand is why $a_1b_1+a_2b_2+a_3b_3$ gives a quantity that is invariant under rotations, but $a_1b_1+a_1b_2+\dots+a_3b_2+a_3b_3$ does *not*. A similar argument applies to Lorentz transformations. Tensor contractions are defined in a way that ensures they produce other tensors.

Answer (score 2):

If we wanted all possible combinations, it would be a bit silly to use the same letter for both indices.

According to the Einstein summation convention, repeated indices are summed over. That is,
$$a^i_{\ \ 00} b^1_{\ \ i1} \equiv \sum_i a^i_{\ \ 00} b^1_{\ \ i1} $$
so your first expression is correct.